# CiviCRM Spark trial and pricing?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civicrm-spark

Am I missing something obvious, or is there nothing in the CiviCRM Spark sign-up process that says what the billing period is? It says 'CiviCRM Spark Hosting - $ 9.50' and that it'll renew automatically, but not how often. Does anyone know? I'm guessing monthly, but would need to know before trying it. Or even better, is there a free trial somewhere that I can't see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's per month. Thanks for raising this issue, we will clarify the site.

You can also contact us on the CiviCRM chat: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/spark or by email: info@civicrm.org.

As per the T&C, you can also ask for a refund after 30 days, if you were not satisfied with the service.

Comment: Thanks. Asking for a refund isn't really the same as a trial period though. But I've found a web host offering free hosting for charities, so I'm evaluating CiviCRM that way.

Comment: I agree, but it does involve work/expenses on our end. We do not monetize this service in any other way. We cover our costs and ensure that the service is reliable. We hope that CiviCRM Spark will help provide a better first impression of CiviCRM.

Answer (score 4):

Looks an interesting service and will suit many and certainly a good way of getting started. I can't see a contact email for the service or a list of the extensions included. I think I've probably already grown beyond this service as I am using a few extensions, but had it been there when I started, it would probably have been quicker that getting it going on another hosting provider.

But to answer you question - it does look to be monthly - see the T&Cs linked from the signup page (direct link https://civicrm.org/spark-terms-and-conditions).

Comment: I really wish there was a CiviCRM SAAS that had a monthly fee structure similar to SquareSpace and NationBuilder

Comment: There are a few. Check out CiviDesk.com, civi-go.net (iXiam), Blackfly, Symbiotic.coop. Admittedly, they all have a different focus / experience.